# Deal with lists in column in data Frame

Tags: pandas

How can i convert column categories
[image]

i want to keep only two first elements from  every list and do one hot encoding on them

Comment: First, avoid image please, use plain text data then what have you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str[0:2]` to get the first two items of each list, then join them with an arbitrary separator, and use `.str.get_dummies` with that same separator:

```
encoded = df['categories'].str[0:2].str.join('|').str.get_dummies('|')
```

For a sample dataframe:

```
>>> df
              x
0  [a, b, c, d]
1     [a, c, b]
2     [a, d, d]

>>> encoded = df['x'].str[0:2].str.join('|').str.get_dummies('|')
>>> encoded
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  0  0
1  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  0  1

>>> df = pd.concat([df, encoded], axis=1)
              x  a  b  c  d
0  [a, b, c, d]  1  1  0  0
1     [a, c, b]  1  0  1  0
2     [a, d, d]  1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Nice use of `str` accessor on list!!!!

Comment: Isn't it odd that it's called `str` though it works for a lot of different types? I always find it pretty strange... :)

Comment: A string is a list after all :D

Comment: Good point actually, I never though of that. dicts are like lists as well, as a matter of fact.